# 平日 - What's the difference between the two readings へいじつ and ひらび?

Tags: kanji, readings, multiple-readings

平日 can be read へいじつ or ひらび. What's the difference between the two readings? Is one more formal than the other?

The basic meaning seems to be "Weekday" (ie Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday)

Comment: As a general tip: You can search in for example jisho.org "平日 ひらび #sentence", which will give you sentences which contain this word with this reading. Or, well, in this case none, which usually is an indication that the reading might be uncommon or archaic. Of course it's not a guarantee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This word is always read へいじつ in modern Japanese. You can safely forget ひらび. As a native speaker, I didn't even know some dictionaries say it can be read ひらび.

(I found two (and only two) actual examples of 平日【ひらび】 on the net ([this](https://navicon.jp/news/54548/) and [this](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000207/files/47123_35877.html)), where ひらび seems to be used in the sense of "ordinary days". But these are very rare, unique, local usages, so you should not follow them.)